# Python - Adding quotes on a multi word phrase in a string

Tags: python, regex, string

Suppose there is a string like follow:

```
'jon doe AND (james OR james david)'
```

What I want to do is to add double quotes around the multi word phrase like in jon doe and in james david as follow:

```
'"jon doe" AND (james OR "james david")'
```

I think it can be possible using regex but not sure how? As I am nooby in regex. I have tried writing my own python code without regex and was able to do so with string which do not have parenthesis. Like follow

```
'jon doe AND james OR james david'
```

to

```
'"jon doe" AND james OR "james david"'
```

but not with the parenthesis.
If anyone has done this before do let me know. Thanks

Edit 1: The method I have wrote is also not neat and clean and thus want a better solution also.

Edit 2: In case someone wants to see the code here it is. It does the job and successfully does what I want but it does not seems to be a nice way. And I am sure there are more good ways than this:

```
s = 'jon doe AND (james OR james david)'
new  = ''
new_list = []
splited = s.split()
for i in range(0, len(splited)):
    word = splited[i]
    if word in ['AND', 'OR', 'NOT']:
        if len(new_list) > 1:
            pharase = ' '.join(x for x in new_list)
            if pharase.endswith(")"):
                pharase = pharase.replace(")", '"')
                new += '"{})'.format(pharase)
            elif pharase.startswith("("):
                pharase = pharase.replace("(", '"')
                new += '({}"'.format(pharase)
            else:
                new += '"{}"'.format(pharase)
            new += " {} ".format(word)
        else:
            pharase = ' '.join(x for x in new_list)
            new += '{}'.format(pharase)
            new += " {} ".format(word)
        new_list = []
    elif i==len(splited)-1:
        new_list.append(word)
        pharase = ' '.join(x for x in new_list)
        if len(new_list) > 1:
            if pharase.endswith(")"):
                pharase = pharase.replace(")", '"')
                new += '"{})'.format(pharase)
            elif pharase.startswith("("):
                pharase = pharase.replace("(", '"')
                new += '({}"'.format(pharase)
            else:
                new += '"{}"'.format(pharase)
        else:
            new += '{}'.format(pharase)
    else:
        new_list.append(word)
```

Output: `'"jon doe" AND (james OR "james david")'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match two or more space-separated words that are not one of the keywords `AND`, `OR` and `NOT`:

```
((?=\S)(?:\s*(?!(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b)\b\w+){2,}\b)
```

And substitute the match with a quoted version:

```
"\1"
```

Regex demo: https://regex101.com/r/KB2Ogb/2

Python demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/BeigeQuietMemoryallocator